# Вывести данные с базы MySQL. SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы

1) products

id | name  | categoryID
------------------------
1  | Cola  | 1
2  | Fanta | 1
3  | Lays  | 2
4  | Tuk   | 2

2) Categories

id | name   | list
-----------------
1  | Juice  | 0
1  | Snacks | 1

Не знаю как написать SQL запрос, чтобы вытащить продукты, где в категории list равен 0.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN Categories AS c ON c.id = p.categoryID
WHERE list = 0
GROUP BY p.id
```